# TypeError thrown when library is included in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, typeerror

I've come across a very peculiar bug that I can't seem to solve. In Node.js, I have an API wrapper library called Markitable:

```
var request = require('request');
var Q = require('q');

/**
 * Markit on Demand API Client
 * @constructor
 * @author Chandler Freeman <chandler.freeman@gmail.com>
 */
var Markitable = function() {

};
module.exports = Markitable;

endpoints = {
    lookup: 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Lookup',
    quote: 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote',
    interactivechart: 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/InteractiveChart'
};

/**
 * Company lookup
 * @httpMethod        GET
 * @param {ticker}    String          A string containing the ticker for the stock
 * @param {callback}  callback        (Optional) If callback is passed, than the function will use callbacks
 * @promises          yes             By default, this function uses promises
 */
Markitable.prototype.lookup = function(ticker, callback) {
    var options = {
        url: endpoints.lookup,
        headers: this.headers,
        qs: { 'input': ticker.toUpperCase() },
        method: 'GET',
        json: true
    };
    if (!callback) {
        var d = Q.defer();
        request(options, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (err) return d.reject(err);
            d.resolve(body);
        });
        return d.promise;
    }
    else
        request(options, callback);
};
```

As you can see, all it does is fetch data from the Markit on Demand API and return a Q promise. However, every time I include the

```
var Markitable = require('markitable');
```

statement anywhere in my code, when I navigate to the / route of my application I receive

```
Failure on / route: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

I am using Express I have absolutely no idea at all why this is happening; I've reread the source several times, checked source control changes, everything, yet I can't find the root of the issue. This behavior only persists when the library is included; as soon as I remove that statement, everything works perfectly. I don't understand because the code for this library was the exact same code I used from another library I wrote, and the first one looks great. Here is the code for my routes file:

```
var User = require('../app/models/user');
var Robinhood = require('marian');
var util = require('util');
var Q = require('q');

module.exports = function(app, passport) {

    // =========================================
    //     Table of Contents(Search by name)
    //
    //  1. Root
    //
    // =========================================

    // ********************* 1. Root *********************

    app.get('/', isLoggedIn, asyncCallback(function*(req, res) {
        rh = new Robinhood(req.user.local.rhtoken);
        var viewData = { user : req.user };
        try {
            // e: <Cannot read property user of undefined>

            viewData.rhUser = yield rh.getUser();
            viewData.rhUser.basic_info = yield rh.getBasicInfo();
            viewData.rhPortfolio = yield rh.getPortfolio();
            viewData.getOrders = yield rh.getOrders();
            viewData.rhAccount = yield rh.getAccount();

            viewData.active = { page : 'dashboard' };
            res.render('main_pages/maindashboard.ejs', viewData);
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log("Failure on / route: " + e);
            res.render('meta/500.ejs');
        }
    }));   
};

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.redirect('/login');
}

// Code originally from James Long
// http://jlongster.com/A-Study-on-Solving-Callbacks-with-JavaScript-Generators
function asyncCallback(gen) {
    return function() {
        return Q.async(gen).apply(null, arguments).done();
    };
}
```

Any ideas about why this strange behavior may be occurring? I can't imagine why importing a library would affect the 'req' object, but somehow it does. Could this be a bug in Express?

EDIT:

Forgot the stack trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
    at Robinhood.getUser (/vagrant/StockFire/node_modules/marian/index.js:110:26)
    at /vagrant/StockFire/app/routes.js:28:40
    at next (native)
    at Function.continuer (/vagrant/StockFire/node_modules/q/q.js:1278:45)
    at /vagrant/StockFire/node_modules/q/q.js:1305:16
    at /vagrant/StockFire/app/routes.js:226:29
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/vagrant/StockFire/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/vagrant/StockFire/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at isLoggedIn (/vagrant/StockFire/app/routes.js:217:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/vagrant/StockFire/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/vagrant/StockFire/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/vagrant/StockFire/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/vagrant/StockFire/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /vagrant/StockFire/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/vagrant/StockFire/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/vagrant/StockFire/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
```

Comment: My assumption would be the error is originating from `req.isAuthenticated()` not setting `req.user`, causing an error here: `rh = new Robinhood(req.user.local.rhtoken);`

Comment: How would the addition of the 'var Markitable = require('markitable');' line influence the Marian(Robinhood) library at all? I don't get this error until that line is added.

Comment: I don't see anything within markitable that would affect req.user being defined. I think it's just a coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. Simple bug, but very hard to find. I discovered that a variable named `endpoints` existed in both libraries, but neither was declared with `var`, meaning that the variable was overwritten since they both existed in the javascript global scope. Lessons learned: Always check variable scope.